# drag and drop generated image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, image

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add_btn').click(function() {  
    var src$ = $('#img_loc').val();
    $('<img>').attr({
        src: src$,
        class: 'canDrag'}).appendTo($('#work_area'));
    });

    $('.canDrag').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('dragMe');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('dragMe');
        }
    );

    $('.dragMe').draggable();
    $('.dropSpace').droppable({
        accept:'.dragMe'
    });
});
```

I want to generate an image with the click of a button that is also instantly draggable and droppable. I've linked my code to jquery and jquery ui (directory path is correct) but im still not able to drag the images. Can anyone offer advice on whats wrong here?

Comment: Side note, you can change the `.hover()` to simply: `$('.canDrag').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('dragMe');
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the draggable declaration to:

```
$('.canDrag').draggable();
```

At he stage where this line is executed there is no `dragMe` class to your image and therefore it's not made draggable.

You probably want the `dragMe` class to give visual indication of draggability but the actual draggable functionality should be probably made always available.

Comment: @Variant--its still not working... it looks like `.draggable()` is not even having an effect. Any other advice?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Variant-- here it is http://jsfiddle.net/j95DF/. Something strange: it works in jsfiddle but not in my browser. This is the same exact code used in both. Why would this be happening?

Comment: Do you reference compatible JQuery & JQueryUI versions? Does your JQueryUI is a full version or partial?

Comment: @Variant--both jquery and jquery ui versions are compatible and full. The directory paths are also correct.

Comment: That is indeed weird. can you upload a stand alone version that displays the problem to some server?